# Why do designers draw graphic layouts without device resolution constraints?

Tags: website-design, graphic-design, page-layout

I am front-end web developer based in Europe. I just begun working remotely with team from USA. I am not a graphics designer. So far when I was cutting and embedding graphical layout into HTML and CSS I had designs made 1:1 pixel. Thanks to that I could measure dimensions right from the PSD file and apply to elements on nascent HTML template.

My new team designer sends designs that do not recreate real views on laptop, the file is not 1024x768 or 1920x[any height here] or any other known resolution. Additionaly we use CSS framework Bootstrap 3, so breakpoints are well known... but when I take a measure of container widths there is no dimension resembling Bootstrap's breakpoints.

As I am used to transfer dimensions from PSD to HTML, the template I did was not satisfying for abroad team.

My question in addition to what I stated in topic is, how should I behave?
What is the way of resolving this misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the way of resolving this misunderstanding?

Speak.

As a dev, sit down with the designers and explain your concerns. If they wish for their designs to be translated on the screen pixel by pixel then explain the constrains you need to work with.

Communication is key here so you are both on the same page and you deliver the product as promised.

Comment: Thanks! I, as a self taught web developer, just thought that I am missing something here. That I am missing some common known usage/habit: designers design with no control over the resolution and devs should cope with that with some special techniques or tools. Turned out, it is just my imposter syndrom :)

Comment: @Marecky we all suffer from imposter syndrome. Hence why we are on sites like StackExchange.

Communication is key. If you are an in-house dev, a freelancer, a nomad, contractor it doesn't matter. Both sides need to meet in the middle. Also, designers tend to enjoy constraints like that. What's the point if there are no challenges right?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Kolios but here is an idea that will help tremendously. **Send them examples of past designs** that you have been given that are ideal. As a graphic designer, I have worked with developers for over 20 years. And no two developers share the same preferential treatment. We designers need to know and should be willing to adapt. We are all on the same team!

Comment: Indeed! I wish my devs ever came to me to give me feedback on the work process.